# When converting categorical data to numeric in R is it important to use the same value to numeric mapping across columns

Tags: r, correlation, caret

If I have a dataset consisting of categorical data and I want to see if there is a correlation between the values I will need to convert it to numeric in order to run corr() in R but I have a few questions about how to do this correctly

I'm a novice when it comes to R and stats so I was wondering if it recommended to use the same mapping of value to numeric and if something like the caret library in R was a good fit to do this.

An example may be to think of a 200 column dataset consisting of product categories columns interspersed with daysOfWeek {Mon - Sun} columns as columns 1, 40 and 160 (no reason, just to space them out)

1. If I use the caret library to create dummy vars will the monday in
   column 1 be represented with the same number as the monday in column
   40 if none of the columns are sorted?
2. If they are are not, does it matter? Will all Monday in Column 1 share
       the same value by default or is there validation needed to handle
       case like mOnday, Monday etc?****

Comment: Let's start at the beginning and forget about the `R` stuff (which is off topic here anyway).  Exactly what do you mean by a "correlation" between *categories*?  (It's almost surely the case that `cor` is not going to give you anything meaningful.)

Comment: I have a dataset with only a handful of numeric columns and I would like to see if there is some relation between the columns. The majority of columns are categorical with the rest date values in 1 form or another.

Comment: Often the first, most basic, and most useful thing to do is to cross-tabulate the columns.  The results might be obvious.  If they are not, you can begin to apply subtler techniques, ranging from $\chi^2$ analyses to generalized linear models, depending on what kinds of relations you are looking for and how you wish to quantify them.  It's a big subject, so any edits you can make to the question to put it in perspective, narrow it, and focus it on your actual problem would be most helpful.

Comment: Would cross-tabulate be suitable when you have a large number of observations about 8000?

Comment: The size of the crosstabs output depends only on the number of distinct categories, not on how many observations there are.

Comment: Do you have a recommended crosstab method which can handle alot of columns and someone who is not sure where to start? [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGKz3Jkx-9I)gives a good intro but I'm not sure how to start the analysis when I don't have a class label or a subset of columns to crosstab against if thats the right terminology. BTW @whuber thanks alot for the help and guidance

Comment: When you're unfamiliar with a statistical procedure, two excellent ways to proceed are (1) practice by applying it to a well-known or simulated dataset (where you know the answer in advance) and (2) create a representative subset of your own data which is so small that you won't be bogged down by the commands or the computations, then practice on this subset before working with the full dataset.  When there is a very large number of categories you might want to reconceptualize your data: maybe they shouldn't be analyzed as categorical at all? Or maybe categories should be grouped?